# Difference between mapValues and transform in Map

Tags: scala, dictionary, scala-collections

In Scala `Map` (see [API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map)) what is the difference in semantics and performance between `mapValues` and `transform` ?

For any given map, for instance

```
val m = Map( "a" -> 2, "b" -> 3 )
```

both

```
m.mapValues(_ * 5)
m.transform( (k,v) => v * 5 )
```

deliver the same result.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Let's say we have a `Map[A,B]`. For clarification: I'm always referring to an immutable `Map`.

`mapValues` takes a function `B => C`, where `C` is the new type for the values.

`transform` takes a function `(A, B) => C`, where this `C` is also the type for the values.

So both will result in a `Map[A,C]`.

However with the `transform` function you can influence the result of the new values by the value of their keys.

For example:

```
val m = Map( "a" -> 2, "b" -> 3 )
m.transform((key, value) => key + value) //Map[String, String](a -> a2, b -> b3)
```

Doing this with `mapValues` will be quite hard.

The next difference is that `transform` is strict, whereas `mapValues` will give you only a view, which will not store the updated elements. It looks like this:

```
protected class MappedValues[C](f: B => C) extends AbstractMap[A, C] with DefaultMap[A, C] {
  override def foreach[D](g: ((A, C)) => D): Unit = for ((k, v) <- self) g((k, f(v)))
  def iterator = for ((k, v) <- self.iterator) yield (k, f(v))
  override def size = self.size
  override def contains(key: A) = self.contains(key)
  def get(key: A) = self.get(key).map(f)
}
```

(taken from https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.2/src/library/scala/collection/MapLike.scala#L244)

So performance-wise it depends what is more effective. If `f` is expensive and you only access a few elements of the resulting map, `mapValues` might be better, since `f` is only applied on demand. Otherwise I would stick to `map` or `transform`.

`transform` can also be expressed with `map`. Assume `m: Map[A,B]` and `f: (A,B) => C`, then

`m.transform(f)` is equivalent to `m.map{case (a, b) => (a, f(a, b))}`

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thanks!

Comment: ```If f is expensive and you only access a few elements of the resulting map, mapValues might be better, since f is only applied on demand```

Be careful that if `f` is expensive and the elements are accessed a lot, using `mapValues` is very bad performance wise.

Answer (score 11):

`collection.Map` doesn't provide `transform`: it has a different signature for mutable and immutable Maps.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_11).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val im = Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2, 'c -> 3)
im: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,Int] = Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2, 'c -> 3)

scala> im.mapValues(_ * 7) eq im
res0: Boolean = false

scala> im.transform { case (k,v) => v*7 } eq im
res2: Boolean = false

scala> val mm = collection.mutable.Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2, 'c -> 3)
mm: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Symbol,Int] = Map('b -> 2, 'a -> 1, 'c -> 3)

scala> mm.mapValues(_ * 7) eq mm
res3: Boolean = false

scala> mm.transform { case (k,v) => v*7 } eq mm
res5: Boolean = true
```

Mutable transform mutates in place:

```
scala> mm.transform { case (k,v) => v*7 }
res6: mm.type = Map('b -> 98, 'a -> 49, 'c -> 147)

scala> mm.transform { case (k,v) => v*7 }
res7: mm.type = Map('b -> 686, 'a -> 343, 'c -> 1029)
```

So mutable transform doesn't change the type of the map:

```
scala> im mapValues (_ => "hi")
res12: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,String] = Map('a -> hi, 'b -> hi, 'c -> hi)

scala> mm mapValues (_ => "hi")
res13: scala.collection.Map[Symbol,String] = Map('b -> hi, 'a -> hi, 'c -> hi)

scala> mm.transform { case (k,v) => "hi" }
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("hi")
 required: Int
              mm.transform { case (k,v) => "hi" }
                                           ^

scala> im.transform { case (k,v) => "hi" }
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,String] = Map('a -> hi, 'b -> hi, 'c -> hi)
```

...as can happen when constructing a new map.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a couple of unmentioned differences:

- `mapValues` creates a Map that is NOT serializable, without any indication that it's just a view (the type is `Map[_, _]`, but just try to send one across the wire).
- Since `mapValues` is just a view, every instance contains the real `Map` - *which could be another result of `mapValues`*. Imagine you have an actor with some state, and every mutation of the state sets the new state to be a `mapValues` on the previous state...in the end you have deeply nested maps with a copy of each previous state of the actor (and, yes, both of these are from experience).