# Scala map() on a Map[..] much slower than mapValues()

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In a Scala program I wrote I have a `scala.collection.Map` that maps a String to some calculated values (in detail it's `Map[String, (Double, immutable.Map[String, Double], Double)]` - I know that's ugly and should (and will be) wrapped). Now, if I do this:

```
stats.map { case(c, (prior, pwc, denom)) => {
  println(c)
  ...
  }
}
```

it takes about 30 seconds to print out roughly 50 times a value of `c`! The `println` is just a test statement - the actual calculation I need was even slower (I aborted after 1 minute of complete silence). However, if I do it like this:

```
stats.mapValues { case (prior, pwc, denom) => {
  println(prior)
  ...
  }
}
```

I don't run into these performance issues ... Can anyone explain why this is happening? Am I not following some important Scala guidelines?

Thanks for the help!

**Edit:**

I further investigated the behaviour. My guess is that the bottleneck comes from accessin the `Map` datastructure. If I do the following, I have have the same performance issues:

```
classes.foreach{c => {
  println(c)
  val ps = stats(c)
  }
}
```

Here `classes` is a `List[String]` that stores the keys of the Map externally. Without the access to `stats(c)` no performance losses occur.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Scala Map, difference between mapValues and transform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635803/in-scala-map-difference-between-mapvalues-and-transform)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapValues` actually returns a view on the original map, which can lead to unexpected performance issues.  From [this](http://blog.bruchez.name/2013/02/mapmap-vs-mapmapvalues.html) blog post:

> ...here is a catch: map and mapValues are different in a not-so-subtle
>   way. mapValues, unlike map, returns a view on the original map. This
>   view holds references to both the original map and to the
>   transformation function (here (_ + 1)). Every time the returned map
>   (view) is queried, the original map is first queried and the
>   tranformation function is called on the result.

I recommend reading the rest of that post for some more details.

Comment: That's definitely good to know! But this blog post would suggest that `mapValues` can be slower than `map`. However, I'm experiencing the opposite...

Comment: Keyword being *can*. If you used `mapValues(someComplexFunction)` and then looked up the value stored for a given key many times, then you would be evaluating `someComplexFunction` many times (as opposed to the single time per key that you would get with `map`).

Comment: Agreed. But the code above only contains a simple `println`, I wouldn't expect such a huge difference in this case ...

Comment: Turns out I've already used a `mapValues` to compute the `stats` Map, which contains some heavy computations. Turning this into a `map` slows down the program at this point already. Thanks for the help!