# Scala: Difference between Map.map and Map.transform? Why Map.map requires pattern matching in its parameter?

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

For an immutable `Map`,

```
val original = Map("A"->1, "B"->2)
```

I can either use

```
original.map { case (k, v) => (k, v + 1) }
```

Or

```
original.transform((_, v) => v + 1)
```

to transform the values.

**But why `map()` method requires `case` pattern matching but `transform()` doesn't? Is it because of these methods are defined in different implicit types?**

---

Someone has marked my question as a duplicate of another question [[Difference between mapValues and transform in Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635803/difference-between-mapvalues-and-transform-in-map]). It is not the same. I am asking Map.map not Map.mapValues. Also I am asking the different way of using the two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform take a function that has two values as inputs, the first is the key and the second the value.  Pattern matching is not needed since the two values are passed in individually.

On the other hand, the function passed to map takes in a single tuple containing the key and value of the element as an input.  Pattern matching is used to break this tuple into it's components.  You don't have to use pattern matching, but that would mean working with the tuple object instead of it's contents.

Answer (score 3):

With `map` method you can change (don't want to use *transform* word here) whole `Map` converting it to another `Map`, `List` etc

```
val m = Map(1->"a")
m.map { case (k,v) => (k+1) -> (v + 1) } // Map(2 -> a1)
m.map { case (k,v) => k+v } // List(1a)
```

With `transform` method you can change only values considering their keys

```
m.transform { case (k, v) => v + 1 } // Map(1 -> a1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the function they receive.  As you can see in the [API](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html)

```
def transform[W, That](f: (K, V) ⇒ W)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Map[K, V], (K, W), That]): That

def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): Map[B]
```

transform's function receives a tuple `f: (K, V) ⇒ W` while map's function receives a single value (which can obviously be a `Tuple`) `f: (A) ⇒ B`

So if you want to treat differently and in a easy-to-read way you should use the case word.

You can also do something like this, but is way less readeable:

```
original.map(r => (r._1, r._2+1))
```

Comment: This is a wrong explanation of the difference: they both receive a tuple, so no difference here.

Comment: Are you sure it is wrong? It seems in the documentation and the original Scala codes, the map method's signature is indeed `def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): Map[B]` whose function parameter receives a single value. When I use IntelliJ IDEA, the auto-completion shows the function parameter receives a tuple not a single value. This is probably misleading?

Comment: @Tyler提督九门步军巡捕五营统领 A tuple is a single value, a single tuple. 
 Transform is different, it receives two values individually instead of as a tuple.  That's only the simplified signature of map, the full signature is `def map[B, That](f: ((K, V)) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Map[K, V], B, That]): That`  Which makes it clear that the function passed in should have a tuple value containing the key and value as inputs.

Comment: So `transform`'s parameter function takes two parameter inputs, which are not a single tuple. `map`'s parameter function takes a single parameter input, which is a tuple (single value). Now it makes more sense..